# Javascript Drop-Down with PHP Function?

Tags: javascript, php, function

I am using this code I found to try and make this drop down menu.
http://www.javascriptkit.com/script/cut183.shtml

Ignore my variables and values, they are all place holders.

The problem is, it calls the value in Javascript, but I want to call a specific function in PHP depending on what option in the menu you chose.

```
<html>
<body>
<form name="doublecombo" form action"index.php" method="POST">
<p><select name="example" size="1" onChange="redirect(this.options.selectedIndex)">
<option>Amazon</option>
<option>Apple</option>
<option>Logitech</option>
<option>Nike</option>
</select>
<select name="stage2" size="1">
<option value="http://javascriptkit.com">Kindle Fire</option>
<option value="http://www.news.com">Kindle DX</option>
<option value="http://www.wired.com">Kindle Charger</option>
<option value="http://www.microsoft.com">Kindle Paperweight</option>
</select>
<input type="button" name="test" value="Generate"
onClick="gen()">
</p>

<script>
var groups=document.doublecombo.example.options.length
var group=new Array(groups)
for (i=0; i<groups; i++)
group[i]=new Array()

group[0][0]=new Option("Kindle Fire","http://javascriptkit.com")
group[0][1]=new Option("Kindle DX","http://www.news.com")
group[0][2]=new Option("Kindle Charger","http://www.wired.com")
group[0][2]=new Option("Kindle Paperweight","http://www.microsoft.com")

group[1][0]=new Option("MacBook","http://www.cnn.com")
group[1][1]=new Option("iPhone","http://www.abcnews.com")
group[1][2]=new Option("iPad","http://www.yahoo.com")
group[1][3]=new Option("iMac","http://www.apple.com")

group[2][0]=new Option("G602 Wireless Gaming Mouse","http://www.hotbot.com")
group[2][1]=new Option("G19s Gaming Keyboard","http://www.infoseek.com")
group[2][2]=new Option("G430 Surround Sound Gaming Headset","http://www.excite.com")
group[2][3]=new Option("PowerShell Controller","http://www.lycos.com")

group[3][0]=new Option("Nike FuelBand","http://www.nike.com")

var temp=document.doublecombo.stage2

function redirect(x){
for (m=temp.options.length-1;m>0;m--)
temp.options[m]=null
for (i=0;i<group[x].length;i++){
temp.options[i]=new Option(group[x][i].text,group[x][i].value)
}
temp.options[0].selected=true
}

function gen(){
location=temp.options[temp.selectedIndex].value
}
</script>
<?
function kindlegen(){
?>
<textarea name="message" placeholder="CODES" rows="10">
<?
{ $amount = "5"; $i = 1; while ($i <= $amount) 
{ $rand_letter1 = substr(str_shuffle("123456789"), 0, 2); $ran = rand(1, 6); echo "D0FB     A0A0 343".$ran." 0A".$rand_letter1."\n"; $i++; } } ?>
</textarea>
<?
}
?>

</form>
</html>
</body>
```

Comment: If you want to call PHP from HTML/JS, you need AJAX.

Comment: Thank you, I will look into that, still curious if that is the only solution, as I finally got this set up so AJAX might be a pain.

Comment: You cannot directly call a PHP function with actions such as `onChange` and similar. Better you can send the data such as chosen option's value or other data to your PHP file via AJAX.

Comment: You have to understand: JavaScript runs on the client, while PHP runs on the server. The two cannot talk to each other except via web requests. One minor exception to that is that you can dump strings of JavaScript code into a page using PHP, either directly or to be called by the JavaScript eval() function. Anyways, @fdsa is correct, you NEED to make some type of web request (doesn't have to be AJAX but they are the most common/easiest). Also remember, AJAX is a way of doing things, not an actual thing itself.

Comment: Yes. PHP runs on the server so you need some way to interact with the server in order to run PHP

Answer (score 0):

PHP is executed server side, HTML and Javascript client side.

This means no, there is **no way** you can execute PHP inside your Javascript (never ever).

You can only post information back to the server, via ajax, which allows you to make further operations. When these are finished on the server, your ajax call receives the result and returns it back to the client for further processing.